# Select multiple elements from dropdown in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select checkbox for OSTPLEX and TNPLX07T. Hence I am code like below :-

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "OSTPLEX"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "TNPLX07T"))).click()
```

However, above code is not working. While selecting 'TNPLX07T', it is deselecting 'OSTPLEX'. Hence, I have decided to check state for respective checkbox. I have observed that, when checkbox is selected, it's value is 1 otherwise it's 0. May I know how can I do this?

```
<div id="EAACAAA_b3" xscroll="1" onmouseleave="hidetreepager(this.firstChild)" onmouseenter="showtreepager(this.firstChild,event.srcElement,event)" onmousemove="showtreepager(this.firstChild,event.srcElement,event)" style="width: 315px; height: 300px; overflow: auto;">
  <div id="members_tree" treeid="members" mode="crittree" multiselect="true" autowidth="true" enabled="" class="xcriteriadropdown-members" onclick="clickcrittree(this,event)" singleselect="F42F61A0">
    <div class="treenoderoot" nodeid="0" state="1" id="ext-gen22">
      <span class="treetext" id="ext-gen23">
        <span></span>
        <img src="images/blank.gif" style="display:none">
        <img src="images/checkbox_checked.png" align="absmiddle" class="treestate" id="ext-gen24">
        <a href="#" id="ext-gen21">No selection</a>
      </span>
      <div class="treechildren" style="display:block;padding-left:0px" id="ext-gen8">
        <div class="treenode" nodeid="1" state="0" id="ext-gen10">
          <div class="treetext" id="ext-gen15">
            <img src="images/blank.gif" nalign="absmiddle">
            <img src="images/checkbox_unchecked.png" class="treestate" nalign="absmiddle" id="ext-gen14">
            <a href="#" id="ext-gen17">?</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="treenode" nodeid="2" state="0">
          <div class="treetext" id="ext-gen16">
            <img src="images/blank.gif" nalign="absmiddle">
            <img src="images/checkbox_unchecked.png" class="treestate" nalign="absmiddle" id="ext-gen13">
            <a href="#" id="ext-gen20">DNBPLEX</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="treenode" nodeid="3" state="0">
          <div class="treetext" id="ext-gen11">
            <img src="images/blank.gif" nalign="absmiddle">
            <img src="images/checkbox_unchecked.png" class="treestate" nalign="absmiddle" id="ext-gen12">
            <a href="#" id="ext-gen19">OSTPLEX</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="treenode" nodeid="4" state="0" id="ext-gen9">
          <div class="treetext" id="ext-gen7">
            <img src="images/blank.gif" nalign="absmiddle">
            <img src="images/checkbox_unchecked.png" class="treestate" nalign="absmiddle">
            <a href="#" id="ext-gen18">TNPLX07T</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="resource.ashx?resname=Misc_Down16&amp;_dc=" 76d3ff65"="" border="0" style="position: absolute; left: -5000px; top: -5000px;" id="ext-gen5">
  <img src="resource.ashx?resname=Misc_Up16&amp;_dc=" 76d3ff65"="" border="0" style="position: absolute; left: -5000px; top: -5000px;" id="ext-gen6">
</div>
```

Comment: when done manually do you need to hold down shift or ctrl to multi-select?

Comment: No. I don't hold down ctrl key.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it through action class?

WebElement option1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("OSTPLEX"));

WebElement option2 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("TNPLX07T"));

new Actions(driver).moveToElement(option1).click().pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))  .moveToElement(option2).click().pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).build().perform();

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for response! However, problem still persist. Moreover, I am getting  'stale element reference' exception. I have asked this in question and reiterating here : I have observed that, when checkbox is selected, it's property 'State' is changed to 1 otherwise it's 0. May I know how can I access 'State' to check it's value?

Comment: As you are stating that state prop is getting changed to 1 after selecting. so you can check state attribute value although after selecting dropdown value.

String stateProp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='OSTPLEX']/parent::div/parent::div").getAttribute("state");

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with javascript once.

```
public void selectMultipleOptions(){
        String[] options = new String[]{"OSTPLEX", "TNPLX07T"};
        String xpath = "//a[text()='%s']";
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        Arrays.stream(options).forEach(x -> {
            WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(xpath, x)));
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", option);
        });
    }
```